# Same edge-connectivity and the minimum degree in bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, graph-connectivity

Let $G$ be a $n$-order bipartite graph.
$\kappa'(G)$ is an edge-connectivity of $G$, and $\delta(G)$ is the minimum degree of $G$.
I want to prove the following theorem:

> If $\delta(G) \geq \frac{n}{4}$, then $\kappa'(G)=\delta(G)$.

And also, I think it is not best possible boundary.
In [Jan Plesnik and Stefan Znam's paper](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/107335/ArchMath_025-1989-1_4.pdf?sequence=2), the boundary $\delta(G) \geq \frac{n+1}{4}$ is the best possible.
But I cannot find their reference, Volkmann's paper.
(Its title is "Bemerkungen zum p-fachen Kantenzusammenhang von graphen".)
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result that $\delta(G) \ge \frac{n+1}{4} \implies \kappa'(G) = \delta(G)$ for bipartite graphs follows from Theorem 3.1 in [the paper you cited](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/107335/ArchMath_025-1989-1_4.pdf).

Let $P \cup Q$ be the bipartition of $G$ with $|P| \ge \frac n2$ and $|Q| \le \frac n2$. Then $\delta(G) > \frac12|Q|$, so any two vertices $x,y \in P$ have a common neighbor in $Q$: condition (ii) of Theorem 3.1 holds.

---

On the other hand, $\delta(G) \ge \frac n4$ is **not** enough to conclude that $\kappa'(G) = \delta(G)$, even when $G$ is bipartite. As mentioned in the same paper, $G$ could be the union of two disjoint copies of $K_{n/4,n/4}$, with $\delta(G)=\frac n4$ but $\kappa'(G)=0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think it would be better to read the paper more carefully. Then can I ask one more thing: If $G$ is connected, then is the statement true?

Comment: No, because if we put one more edge between the two copies of $K_{n/4,n/4}$, we get a connected bipartite graph with $\delta(G) = \frac n4$ but $\kappa'(G)=1$.

Comment: Hmm...In fact, this is from exercise set of our lecture note. It says "Let $G$ be an $n$-vertex bipartite graph. Prove that if $\delta(G) \geq n/4$, then $\kappa'(G)=\delta(G)$. \textit{Is this sharp?}". I thought it was a typo, but now, it seems that my professor did something wrong. I will ask him immediately. Anyway, thanks for providing a nice example!